# Is it superfluous to declare # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- after #!/usr/bin/python3?

Tags: python, utf-8

I have been writing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But I believe Python3 uses Unicode by default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default encoding for python3 code *is* utf-8.  See [python's unicode support](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support).

If you want to support python2.x in the same file or if you want to use a coding other than utf-8, you need that comment, otherwise you can leave it off without any repercussions.